# Hibernate deletes occurring out of order

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following classes:

**Category**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category", schema = "customer")
public class Category extends CustomerOwned {
   ...
}
```

**CatalogueItem**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "catalogue_item", schema = "customer")
@EntityListeners(value = { CatalogueItemStatusListener.class })
public class CatalogueItem extends CatalogueOwned implements Statusable<CatalogueItem, CatalogueItemStatus> {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "catalogueItem", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CatalogueItemCategory> categories;
    ...
}
```

**CatalogueItemCategory**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "catalogue_item_category", schema = "customer")
public class CatalogueItemCategory extends CatalogueItemOwned implements CategoryOwner {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private Category category;
    ...
}
```

We perform very few hard deletes in our application, but **Category**s are hard deleted. **CatalogueItemCategory**s are also hard deleted.

I'm creating a service to allow someone to delete a Category and at the same time I check all Category dependencies and delete those too, so I'm doing this:

```
@Transactional
public DependentItemsResultResource delete(String categoryId, boolean force) {
    List<CatalogueItem> catalogueItems = catalogueItemRepository.getByCategory(getCustomerStringId(), categoryId);

    DependentItemsResultResource resultResource = new DependentItemsResultResource();
    resultResource.setDependentCatalogueItems(new SearchResponse().from(catalogueItems, CatalogueItemSummaryResource::new));

    if (!catalogueItems.isEmpty()) {
        if (!force) {
            resultResource.setDeleted(false);
            return resultResource;
        }

        catalogueItems.forEach(item -> {
            item.getCategories().removeIf(catalogueItemCategory -> categoryId.equals(catalogueItemCategory.getCategory().getStringId()));
            sendEvent(prepareEvent(new CatalogueItemUpdatedEvent(), item.getCatalogue().getStringId(), item.getStringId()));
        });
    }

    Category category = getCategory(categoryId);
    resultResource.setDeleted(true);
    categoryRepository.delete(category);

    CategoryDeletedEvent event = new CategoryDeletedEvent();
    event.setCategoryPath(category.getPath());
    sendEvent(prepareEvent(event, categoryId));
    return resultResource;
}
```

This is causing the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKLYKUEHJG9UL0LR36O5XDD3MLF: CUSTOMER.CATALOGUE_ITEM_CATEGORY FOREIGN KEY(CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER.CATEGORY(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from customer.category where id=? [23503-192]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:426)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowRefTable(ConstraintReferential.java:443)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:318)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:967)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:985)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:101)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 109 common frames omitted
```

I've tried replacing this bit:

```
item.getCategories().removeIf(catalogueItemCategory -> categoryId.equals(catalogueItemCategory.getCategory().getStringId()));
```

with this:

```
item.getCategories().stream()
    .filter(catalogueItemCategory -> categoryId.equals(catalogueItemCategory.getCategory().getStringId()))
    .forEach(catalogueItemCategoryRepository::delete);
```

but it's not making any difference. Hibernate is deleting the objects out of order. It should be deleting the CatalogueItemCategory objects **before** the Category objects, but it's not.

How do I get it to delete in the correct order?

---

Edit: missed this class which provides the parent of the CatalogueItemCategory:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class CatalogueItemOwned extends Updateable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "catalogue_item_id", nullable = false, insertable = true)
    private CatalogueItem catalogueItem;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Behavior of CascadeType.REMOVE for OneToMany relationship without parent-child relationship is unspecified.

Comment: I should point out that I tried playing around with the CascadeType on the List<CatalogueItemCategory>, but nothing helped except removing it entirely and when I did that the CatalogueItemCategory objects stopped getting persisted in the list (during the previous "add" operation). The first thing I tried was removing the CascadeType.REMOVE.

Comment: orphanRemoval = true will switch on CascadeType.REMOVE implicitly

Comment: So you mean: 1) remove orphanRemoval AND 2) CascadeType.REMOVE? This will be problematic because the normal removal of CatalogueItemCategory objects depends on orphanRemoval.

Comment: That's the way JPA works, you can't Cascade.REMOVE if there is no parent-child relationship.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm not trying to cascade the removal of Category from CatalogueItemCategory. I'm trying to: 1) remove the CatalogueItemCategory objects from the CatalogueItem; and then 2) remove the Category. If I was doing this in SQL, I'd do it in exactly that order and I wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: So Category and CatalogueItemCategory are not related at all?

Comment: Category is just a thing that is used by other objects. For example we have tax categories that are linked to taxes using a TaxCategory linking entity. CatalogueItemCategory is just the linking table to CatalogueItem (I'm aware that we can link these without an entity, but there are reasons why we use linking entities).

Comment: have you tried with JPA native sql query to perform your requirement.

Comment: It might be provider optimization, try to delete in different methods without transaction propagation.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu I thought about that, but it will cause our unit tests to fail. It seems to me like this should work with OOTB JPA. It doesn't seem an odd scenario to me.

Comment: If you use native SQL query it will bypass persistence context, and your persistence context will be unsynchronized, use JPQL instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are dirty solutions, that are both anti-pattern, but would probably work:

Either use a `flush` after each delete, or delete with a native query.

That said, I recommend not to use any of these solutions, but to search for a cleaner solution.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I tried this before posting the problem. Flush after the delete didn't work. Didn't seem to do anything. I adding logging before and after the delete/flush and nothing got printed in the log between them.

Comment: Note that I have not used a native query yet. In the meantime, I've reported this as a sequencing bug to the Spring Boot team.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by explicitly deleting the category and all dependencies as follows:

```
@Transactional
public DependentItemsResultResource delete(String categoryId, boolean force) {
    List<CatalogueItem> catalogueItems = catalogueItemRepository.getByCategory(getCustomerStringId(), categoryId);

    DependentItemsResultResource resultResource = new DependentItemsResultResource();
    resultResource.setDependentCatalogueItems(new SearchResponse().from(catalogueItems, CatalogueItemSummaryResource::new));

    if (!catalogueItems.isEmpty()) {
        if (!force) {
            resultResource.setDeleted(false);
            return resultResource;
        }

        catalogueItems.forEach(item -> sendEvent(prepareEvent(
            new CatalogueItemUpdatedEvent(), item.getCatalogue().getStringId(), item.getStringId())));
    }

    Category category = getCategory(categoryId);
    resultResource.setDeleted(true);
    categoryRepository.deleteCatalogueItemCategoriesByCategory(category);
    categoryRepository.deleteCategory(category);

    CategoryDeletedEvent event = new CategoryDeletedEvent();
    event.setCategoryPath(category.getPath());
    sendEvent(prepareEvent(event, categoryId));
    return resultResource;
}
```

The repo methods are:

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from Category c where c = :category")
void deleteCategory(@Param("category") Category category);
```

and

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from CatalogueItemCategory where category = :category")
void deleteCatalogueItemCategoriesByCategory(@Param("category") Category category);
```

Not the best, but also not the worst. Not using native deletes and it's still within the main transaction.